# IE doesn't evaluate meta-refresh anymore after pressing F5

Tags: html, internet-explorer, refresh

Ridiculous simple HTML-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=./test.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open the file with *any* browser, the browsers behave well and reload the page every 5 seconds.

But when I refresh the page manually between two refreshes (<kbd>F5</kbd>), the **IE (V 8.0.6001.18702)** doesn't evaluate the `meta` tag anymore and the page gets no longer refreshed. [Opera](http://www.opera.com/), [FF](http://www.mozilla.org/) and [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) still work as expected and refresh every 5 seconds.

Has anybody else experienced such a problem? How (apart of using Javascript, of course) could this issue be solved?

---

**Edit 1:**
Verified this behavior also on IE6, so I guess it's a general IE problem. Any hints how to overcome this?

---

**Edit 2:**
To keep that topic going:

- is that a known problem or would it
  be worth to file a bug ticket
  somewhere (where?)?
- Could someone
  verify that behavior with IE7 and/or
  IE9?

Comment: Generally speaking, use of the non-standard META-REFRESH is frowned upon by the standards bodies. Having said that, did you try with a fully qualified URL instead of the relative URL? If you're trying to reload the same page over and over again, did you try omitting the URL entirely?

Comment: @EricLaw: make this an answer and I'll check it! Omitting the URL really solves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE 9 it works fine.

P.S. you missed a few quotation marks should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;" URL="./test.html">
```

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;" URL="./test.html">` works for me. I tend to accept your answer (and award the bounty) because this variant also promises to work if I have a different URL to reload (what cannot be used when taking Eric's answer)

Comment: "Promises to work" meaning "Doesn't work but looks like it would"?

Comment: @EricLaw: Works when I try it locally, must check it's behavior when the page gets fetched through a webserver. Your answer works, but I cannot specify a URL to reload. In my actual setup, I call a different URL that redirects me to the page where the `<meta http-equiv=...` is provided.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know theres only the mta or javascript way.

Another option might be to use

```
header("Location: url");
```

if you can use php, its not really a refresh in it common way, but you could use to redirect to the same page again

As with the meta way, did you tried to put a full url? ( IE, arrg )

Comment: AFAIK, the drawback of `header("Location: url");` is that you cannot specify a timeout...

Comment: I forgot, what about `header( "refresh:5;url=url");` never confirmed, but ive heard it react similar as your IE 8 problem

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, use of the non-standard META-REFRESH is frowned upon by the standards bodies. Having said that, did you try with a fully qualified URL instead of the relative URL? If you're trying to reload the same page over and over again, did you try omitting the URL entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, I suspect your URL is not setup correctly

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This always refresh itself.

Hope helps
:)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is going to be your friend for this one... it ends up working a lot better across browsers for the most part. Besides, `meta-refresh` is [going out of style](http://davidwalsh.name/meta-refresh-javascript).

The following script and body `onload` attribute will continuously refresh the page every 5 seconds.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
       setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    }
   </script>
   <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
   </noscript>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:timedRefresh(5000)">
   <!-- Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Isaac: I wrote in my question, that javascript is not an option. -1.

Comment: Yes, well I am afraid that you are going to be stuck then. `Meta-refresh` is depreciated, and it's behavior is erratic on a browser by browser basis. I would suggest really trying to make Javascript work. Otherwise, you don't have any options.

Comment: @Crossdiver: it's a requirement for our web pages that they MUST work when JS is disabled. Therefore, I have to provide a non-javascript solution.

Comment: @eckes - OK, I just added some code that is used on ESPN.com to do their legacy browser refreshing. This code will work the best under a JS browser, but has fallback for legacy browsers. (-1) + (+1) = 0?

Comment: @Crossdiver: Meta refresh is not deprecated. This is wrong info. The only thing that W3 says is that it is not recommended to automatically refresh pages because it can be disorienting for some users. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh

Comment: @Midas - I stand corrected. Sorry for the misinformation. At the same time, meta-refresh is not as flexible as Javascript, so I would still recommend using it as a fallback and not as your main refresh method. What do you think?

Comment: @Crossdiver: Yes, if that can solve the problem. But the OP is asking for a solution without JS.